# Permissions of an automount ntfs partition

Tags: mount, permissions, ntfs, qbittorrent

Hi there I have an `ntfs partition` which is mounted automatically on `ubuntu`'s startup.

In `qBittorrent` I have the default download folder is that `ntfs partition`, but after I mount the partition automatically, I always have this message when I run `qBittorrent` :

> An I/O error occured for torrent XXX
>   Error: permission denied.

I tried to unmount the `ntfs partition` but I get that the authentication is required to unmount it, so I think the partition is mounted by the `root` user.

In the `/etc/fstab` file, this is the line which auto-mount the `ntfs partition` :

```
UUID=32EA23CFEA238DE3 /media/Backup ntfs rw,auto,users,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=46,uid=1000    0   0
```

So, I think if the partition was mounted as me, I won't see this error message.

In the other hand, I tried to run `qBittorrent` as the `root` user, but I'm not seeing any of my downloads in the it.

how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong options for your ntfs partition in `/etc/fstab` Some of the options you use, such as "rw" and "exec" are invalid when mounting a ntfs partition.

If you read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) for mount you will see the options.

I know it is a long page, scroll down to the ntfs section.

You want to mount the ntfs partition with ntfs-3g, not ntfs ([see here](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/)).

The options for ntfs (ntfs-3g) are [here](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.ntfs-3g). I suggest you use

```
UUID=32EA23CFEA238DE3 /media/Backup ntfs-3g auto,users,permissions,nls=utf8  0 0
```

you can then set ownership and permissions using `chown` and `chmod`

If that does not work, you can set ownership and permissions

```
UUID=32EA23CFEA238DE3 /media/Backup ntfs auto,users,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=46,uid=1000 0 0
```